# OAuth Authorization code flow with PKCE does not trigger /token API to get token

Tags: angular, azure, oauth-2.0, azure-ad-msal

I have an Angular 11 app which wants to integrate with Azure (using MSAL) do perform OAuth authentication code flow with PKCE. However, I saw that my app has called the `/authorize`  (returned 302) and then redirected to `http://localhost:8087/home#code=THE_RETURN_CODE from above`. Then the app does not do anything more and just give me a blank page. I cannot see any `/token` being called. Instead its stayed at `http://localhost:8087/home#code=....`

My config:

```
export function MSALInstanceFactory(): IPublicClientApplication {
      return new PublicClientApplication({
        auth: {
          clientId: CLIENT_ID,
          authority: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/TENANT_ID',
          redirectUri: 'http://localhost:8087/home',
          postLogoutRedirectUri: 'http://localhost:8087/home',
          navigateToLoginRequestUrl: true
        },
        cache: {
          // cacheLocation: BrowserCacheLocation.LocalStorage,
            cacheLocation: "sessionStorage",
          storeAuthStateInCookie: isIE, // set to true for IE 11. Remove this line to use Angular Universal
        },
        system: {
          loggerOptions: {
            loggerCallback,
            logLevel: LogLevel.Info,
            piiLoggingEnabled: false
          }
        }
      });
    }
```

Blank page:
[image]

Comment: Could you perhaps provide some more detail? What is the expected/desired behaviour? Where is the code that is supposed to do it? A minimal repo to reproduce it if possible would be great.

Comment: hi @RJM I expected the /token API will be called automatically followed by the /authorize

Comment: This could use a bit more detail -- we see the auth `config` but not any sort of implementation. How, when and where does the app first check auth state?

Answer (score 0):

In the **authorization code flow** (RFC 6749 [Section 4.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1)), a client application has to make 2 API calls. The first one is an **authorization request** (RFC 6749 [Section 4.1.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1.1)) via a web browser. The second one is a **token request** (RFC 6749 [Section 4.1.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1.3)). The token endpoint (`/token` in your case) is not called automatically.

The program which is waiting at the **redirection endpoint** (`http://localhost:8087/home` in your case) must retrieve the issued **authorization code** (`THE_RETURN_CODE` in your case) from the **authorization response** (RFC 6749 [Section 4.1.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1.2)) and make a token request with the authorization code.